# How to create a Webform pre-build option list via a query to an external database?

Tags: webforms, database

I'm trying in [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (version 4.9) to create a *pre-build option list* with data from an external database. A *pre-build option list* is an available list you get when creating a "select options" field in Webform (like list of countries, state, ...).

I didn't find an existing module that allows me to add such pre-build list to Webform.

So, first I added my external database information to the `setting.php` file.

To test it, I build a simple php page containing this:

```
db_set_active('external_db');
$query = db_query("SELECT id, name FROM TABLE")->fetchAllKeyed();
db_set_active();
Print_r($query);
```

And, it's working (= I got a correct result of my request).

So then I added this to my `.module` file:

```
function webform_pre_build_list_db_webform_select_options_info() {
    $items = array();
    $items['modeles_db'] = array(
        'title' => t('Modeles_db'),
        'options callback' => 'webform_pre_build_list_db'
    );

   return $items;
}

function webform_pre_build_list_db() {

db_set_active('external_db');

return db_query('SELECT id, name FROM table')->fetchAllKeyed();

db_set_active('default');

}
```

And, it's **not** working (= my list is empty).

If I try with a request to the Drupal DB, then, it's working. For example:

```
function webform_pre_build_list_db() {
return db_query('SELECT cid, recipients FROM contact')->fetchAllKeyed();
}
```

Is working well, I got recipients form drupal table "contact" in my list...

What am I missing?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: first of all you are using `db_set_active('default');`  after `return` statement, next - read about [db_set_active](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7) probably you need to clear cache

Comment: What's a "Webform prebuild list"? Also, would it be an option to use an (existing) contributed module instead of writing your own module? If you want to answer these questions, then please do so via an EDIT of your question.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, I have edited my post.

Comment: @Neok, Yes to go back to default Drupal DataBase, but I change to "external_db" before return. I already tried clearing cache. Thanks!

Comment: OK, now the question is way more clear. I hope my extra edits are OK (also). If not please rework as you like ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, edits sound good for me :), now let's hope for an answer ;) thank you!

Comment: @Fumble try to debug with `Xdebug`, or `var_dump` atleast inside webform_pre_build_list_db

Answer (score 1):

I changed this:

```
function webform_pre_build_list_db() {
db_set_active('external_db');
return db_query('SELECT id, name FROM table')->fetchAllKeyed();
db_set_active('default');
}
```

to this

```
function webform_pre_build_list_db() {
  db_set_active('external_db');
  $options = db_query('SELECT id, name FROM table')->fetchAllKeyed();
  db_set_active('default');
  return $options;
}
```

And it's working!

(Explanation: *return* immediately ends the execution of a function, in this case before `db_set_active()` could be called.)

Thanks to [Nevets](https://www.drupal.org/u/nevets)